# set maxlength in textarea

Tags: textarea, maxlength

I want to set maxlength in textarea. I have defined maxlength property in textarea but it seems to be of no use. Pls help. My code:

```
<html:textarea styleClass="textarea" maxlength="2100" cols="60" rows="3">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this javascript function:

```
$(function(){  
  $("#id").keypress(function() {  
    var maxlen = 100; //length as you desire
    if ($(this).val().length > maxlen) {  
      return false;
    }  
  })
});
```

Comment: or just get the length at submit time and do validation.

Comment: it fails if someone copy-paste the text.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write code for two events, keyup and copy paste so try this:

```
onKeyPress = "return ( this.value.length < 2100 );", onPaste = "return onTextAreaPaste(this,2100)"
```

Here is Js:

```
function onTextAreaPaste(textArea,size) {        
    var length = textArea.value.length;
    if(window.clipboardData!=undefined)
        length = textArea.value.length + window.clipboardData.getData('Text').length;
    return length < size;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a problem with textarea maxlength attribute because the newlines where considered as **1 in Firefox**, and **2 in IE and Chrome**. So I decide to go for **JavaScript** for handling this.

[Here is how I handle the max length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22383182/31973620), its a **jquery plugin**, very easy to set and there's no problem with the different behaviors of browsers, plus give you a feedback of the characters used.